# How to reverse cohen-sutherland algorithm?

Tags: c#

Here is the Cohen-Sutherland code:

```
public static Tuple<PointF, PointF> ClipSegment(RectangleF r, PointF p1, PointF p2)
        {
            //classify the endpoints of the line
            var outCodeP1 = ComputeOutCode(p1, r);
            var outCodeP2 = ComputeOutCode(p2, r);
            var accept = false;
            while (true)
            { 
                // Case 1!
                if ((outCodeP1 | outCodeP2) == OutCode.Inside)
                {
                    accept = true;
                    break;
                }
                // Case 2!
                if ((outCodeP1 & outCodeP2) != 0)
                {                    
                    break;
                }

                //Case 3!
                var outCode = outCodeP1 != OutCode.Inside ? outCodeP1 : outCodeP2; 
                // calculate the intersection of the line with the clipping rectangle using parametric line equations
                var p = CalculateIntersection(r, p1, p2, outCode);
                // update the point after clipping and recalculate outcode
                if (outCode==outCodeP1)
                {
                    p1 = p;
                    outCodeP1 = ComputeOutCode(p1, r);
                }
                else
                {
                    p2 = p;
                    outCodeP2 = ComputeOutCode(p2, r);
                }
            }
            // if clipping area contained a portion of the line
            if (accept)
            {
                return new Tuple<PointF, PointF>(p1, p2);
            }
            // the line did not intersect the clipping area 
            return null;
        }
```

Case 1: both endpoints are within the clipping region.

Case 2: both endpoints share an excluded region, impossible for a line between them to be within the clipping region.

Case 3: the endpoints are in different regions, and the segment is partially within the clipping rectangle, selects one of the endpoints outside the clipping rectangle.

I try to get all segments outside the clipping window instead of inside.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After realising that finding the segments outside of the clipping region may yield multiple tuples and updating the method's return type, it's a matter of just walking through the logic and reversing each decision:

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<PointF, PointF>> ClipSegment(RectangleF r, PointF p1, PointF p2)
{
    // classify the endpoints of the line
    var outCodeP1 = ComputeOutCode(p1, r);
    var outCodeP2 = ComputeOutCode(p2, r);
    var results = new List<Tuple<PointF,PointF>>();
    while (true)
    { 
        // Case 1:
       // both endpoints are within the clipping region
        if ((outCodeP1 | outCodeP2) == OutCode.Inside)
        {
            //Completely clipped
            break;
        }
        // Case 2:
        // both endpoints share an excluded region, impossible for a line between them to be within the clipping region
        if ((outCodeP1 & outCodeP2) != 0)
        {
            //Not clipped at all
            results.Add(Tuple.Create(p1,p2));                    
            break;
        }
        //Case 3: The endpoints are in different regions, and the segment is partially within
        //the clipping rectangle Select one of the endpoints outside the clipping rectangle

        var outCode = outCodeP1 != OutCode.Inside ? outCodeP1 : outCodeP2; 
        // calculate the intersection of the line with the clipping rectangle using parametric line equations
        var p = CalculateIntersection(r, p1, p2, outCode);
        // update the point after clipping and recalculate outcode
        if (outCode==outCodeP1)
        {
            //Keep "discarded" segment
            results.Add(Tuple.Create(p1,p));
            p1 = p;
            outCodeP1 = ComputeOutCode(p1, r);
        }
        else
        {
            //ditto
            results.Add(Tuple.Create(p,p2));
            p2 = p;
            outCodeP2 = ComputeOutCode(p2, r);
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

And you can change the calling code to:

```
var clipped = CohenSutherland.ClipSegment(_rect, p1, p2);
newLines.AddRange(clipped);
```

(Since we now guarantee to always return a list, even if empty, the `null` check is no longer required).

One improvement that we may wish to consider is to change the function to be an iterator and use `yield return` instead of maintaining a separate list internally.